# What's the shortcut for plus (adding) and minus (removing) by default

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

In list elements inside System Preferences, I see a "plus" and a "minus" to add or remove elements (see photo below for example of Networking System Preferences).

[image]

In Windows these are usually associated with <kbd>Insert</kbd> / <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Is there keyboard shortcuts for these keys? I am trying to add keyboard shortcuts in preference without using a mouse but I have to rely on tab key to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think there's any way of doing this built into OS X, but there are apps that will allow it. I use Shortcat (https://shortcatapp.com) which allows you to "click" onscreen elements by typing. I just tried in the Network pane in System Preferences, and typing 'add' in Shortcat focuses on the + button. Typing 'dele' was enough to select the - button.

Comment: @JayThompson Exactly what I needed. Thanks! This is a great start for me with OS X!

Comment: You can also go to System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts. There's a setting to enable "All Controls" for full keyboard access on windows and dialogs. Then you can just press tab to highlight the buttons you need to click. Useful thorough the system.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Tab and Spacebar

You can use the <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> key to move between elements, then press <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the element. As long as the pane (Network Preferences in this example) has focus, you can use this method.   Below is an example of using this method with the Network Preferences pane.

<sup>Please note that I move the mouse cursor to highlight *where* I am going to select, but watch for the element animation as I press the tab button.  The mouse is **not** being used other than a visual aid in this animation.</sup>

[image]

This feature works even in Recovery Mode should your mouse not be functional.

Comment: Wrong and wrong @Thinkr.  This answer **did not** come from any comment and [Keyboard Navigation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-your-keyboard-like-a-mouse-mchlp1399/mac) is to use your keyboard as a mouse.  The `Tab` and `Space` as selection tools have been around since the PowerPC days and even before that with Mac OS 9.  Please stop guessing at a  reply for everything.

Comment: I thought you needed to enable this setting for your answer to work. Excuse me for the disruptancy my comment may have caused you

Comment: @Allan AFAIK this function is disabled by default, so in order to use it, user has to enable it in Preferences.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek i’ve never enabled mine and still haven’t and it works.  I’ve used this in emergencies when the mouse was dead or missing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way of doing this is OS X as well as in macOS. If you take a look at [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), there's none of them indicating this option.

However, you can use a third-party app, [Shortcat](https://shortcat.app/), which allows you to "click" onscreen elements by typing.

When entering "add" for *System Preferences > Network* in Shortcat, it selects the wanted "+" button. To select the "-" button, entering "dele" is sufficient.

Answer (score -3):

Alt 0177 ±
Hold ALT key and type 0177 on keypad

https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/list/